# SparkStreaming/Kafka Offset handling

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to integrate Spark/Kafka to build a streaming app.
Kakfa version: 0.9
spark: 1.6.2

how do i handle offsets after processing data in RDD batch.

Can you give me more insight on handling offsets?

Does spark had inbuilt to store and read offsets automatically? or do i need to guide spark to read offsets from some store like mongo or oracle?

```
JavaInputDStream<String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jsc, String.class, String.class,
                StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, String.class, kafkaParams, topicMap,
                (Function<MessageAndMetadata<String, String>, String>) MessageAndMetadata::message);

        directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question depends on your desired message delivery semantics:

- *at most once*: each message will be processed at most once
- *at least once*: each message will be processed at most once
- *exactly once*: at most once and at least once at the same time

First of all, I would recommend reading [those slides](http://koeninger.github.io/kafka-exactly-once/#1) as well as [this blog post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/exactly-once-spark-streaming-from-apache-kafka/).

I am assuming that you are pursuing *exactly-once*, since the remaining ones are pretty easy to figure out. Anyway, a couple of approaches to consider:

## Checkpointing

Spark Streaming allows you to checkpoint your `DStreams`. If you use direct Stream from `KafkaUtils`, the offsets will be checkpointed as well. The streaming job might fail anywhere between checkpoints, so some messages might get replayed. To achieve *exactly once* semantics with this approach, one would have to use idempotent output operation (in other words - the downstream system is able to distinguish/ignore replayed messages).

**Pros**: easy to achieve; comes out-of-the-box

**Cons**: *at least once* semantics; checkpoints become invalidated after code change; offsets are stored in Spark, not in Zookeeper

## Transactional data storage

You might want to store the offsets yourself in a custom data store that supports transactions, i.e a relational database like MySQL. In this case you need to make sure that processing stream and saving offsets are contained in a single transaction.

**Pros**: *exactly once* semantics

**Cons**: harder to set up, requires a transactional data store

## WAL-based Receiver

You can use the older Kafka connector based on WAL.

**Pros**: works with other data sources as well; stores offsets in Zookeeper
**Cons**: it depends on HDFS; you cannot access offsets directly; it makes parallelism harder to achieve

To sum up, it all depends on your requirements - perhaps you can lift some restrictions to simplify this problem.

Answer (score -1):

When you want to consume data from Kafka topic using Spark Streaming, there are two ways you can do that.

**1.Receiver based approach**
In this approach , offsets are managed in Zookeeper and it is automatically update the offsets in zookeeper. For more information.
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html#approach-1-receiver-based-approach

**2. Direct Approach(No Receiver)** 
This approach is that it does not update offsets in Zookeeper, hence Zookeeper-based Kafka monitoring tools will not show progress. However, you can access the offsets processed by this approach in each batch and update Zookeeper yourself.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers

Comment: This answer is very broad and more over it's just copy of spark documentation!